# I would like to run an exe file with os.startfile, but the file does not run completely all the way through

Tags: python, operating-system

I am running a code that simply runs an exe file with python:
import os
os.startfile("File.exe")

but when I run the code, the window (File.exe) will start to run then close immediately. Not really sure what is going on...

not sure what to do here. The code is pretty strait forward so I was wondering if it is a security issue with the computer. When I run the file from the file explorer it works fine but it doesnt seem to run all the way through from the program.

Comment: Is `File.exe` expecting arguments?

Comment: No, its just the file I would like to run. No arguments.

Comment: What is `File.exe` expected to do? Using `os.startfile()` is the equivalent of double clicking the file. Here is a [tutorial](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter16_os.html#os-startfile) on it.

Comment: the exe is supposed to pull from a bunch of python files and send emails, process data etc. when I double click the exe file on its own it works just fine, but when I run the 'startfile' program i start getting errors from the python files the exe file pull from, saying that certain files and directories are are not found.

Comment: Ahh, this makes more sense. It sounds like the issues has to do with relative vs absolute paths. Let say that your `File.exe` is stored in `/home/username/Desktop` and it looks for a file in `../Documents/Filename.py` to pull data from. If your python program that uses `os.startfile("File.exe")` is not in the same working directory as `File.exe`, it will not be able to find the file. You can check your current working directory with `os.getcwd()` and change your working directory with `os.chdir(path)`. Where `path` is the location of `File.exe`.

Comment: Awesome. it worked! Thank you so much! Not to familiar with paths and directories and stuff like that. So if I would have put the file in the location where the 'os.getcwd()' spit out, the program would have worked?

Comment: No problem. If by `file` you mean the `File.exe` it won't work. It seems that `File.exe` depends on being in its current path location for it to function properly.